# Get last item in dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

I can get the first item by doing `ds.items()(0)`

How can I get the last item? [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9h9579(v=vs.84).aspx), .count will give you the number of items in the dictionary, but 
`ds.items()(ds.count)` gives me a "Subscript out of range" error.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's zero based I had to do `ds.items()(ds.count - 1)`.

`ds.items()(UBound(ds.Items))` also worked.

Comment: `ds.Items()(UBound(ds.Items))`, or `ds.Items()(ds.Count-1)`. Using `UBound(ds.Count)` would raise an error since `ds.Count` doesn't return an array.